# execute windows code in Visual studio 2015 with xamarin plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using the xamarin platform.

1. I have source code which is developed in C# for Windows develop in Visual Studio 2013
2. I have Visual Studio 2015 (Profession) in my system 1st time.
3. Want to check my windows code is compatible to xamarin plugin supported by visualstudio 2015 or not.

**Note:** I know that Visual studio 2015 have facilitate with the xamarin.

**Reason:** I want to reuse code develop in C# for Windows in xamarin so that I can reuse the code & develop the ios & Android application utilising xamarin in Visual Studio.

How do I perform this?

Comment: There were official blog posts revealing the principles, so you should follow, https://blog.xamarin.com/porting-existing-net-apps-to-four-mobile-platforms-with-pcl/

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely reuse your existing C# code with Xamarin project. However, you will need to recompile the code to target Xamarin profiler, unless you're using Portable Class libraries

You can read more about code sharing options here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didnot understand when you say "recomplie the code to target xamrine profiler". How to set the target as xamrine profiler in visual studio ?Please advice me.

Comment: You have to create a new Xamarin.iOS/Android project, add existing C# files to the project and compile